# filebeat send messages to certain index

Tags: linux, filebeat, elk

I have an installed pair elasticsearch - logstash - kibana, 2 clients: ELKclient1 and  ELKclient2. Filebeat is installed on clients. I need that both clients write logs in separate index,  ELKclient1 in index test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd, ELKclient2 in index test2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd (sending nginx access logs). For some reason logs from clients are written in both indexes, eg, from client ELKclient2 logs are written in both indexes test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd and test2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd (attachment 1 and attachement 2). Do you have any clue why its happening?

[image]

[image]

```
#config filebeat on client2
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
      - /var/log/nginx/access.log
  fields:
    type: nginx_access
  fields_under_root: true
  scan_frequency: 5s

registry_file: /var/lib/filebeat/registry
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: ["ip-address_logstash:5044"]
    index: "test2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    bulk_max_size: 1024

shipper:
logging:
  to_syslog: false
  to_files: true
  level: info
  files:
    path: /var/log/filebeat
    name: filebeat.log

#config logstash output
output {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts    => "localhost:9200"
            index    => "test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
        #stdout { codec => rubydebug }
        elasticsearch {
            hosts    => "localhost:9200"
            index    => "test2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
        #stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make both clients write logs in a separate index, Take the workflow idea in the below picture, You need to add a tag to differentiate the logs coming from different servers.

[image]

Considering your requirement in your question one of the ways is to put the following code in the output section of your logstash config file.

```
output {
  if [beat][hostname] == "ELKclient1"
    elasticsearch {
            hosts    => "localhost:9200"
            index    => "test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
  else if [beat][hostname] == "ELKclient2"
    elasticsearch {
            hosts    => "localhost:9200"
            index    => "test2-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
  else 
    stdout { 
      codec => rubydebug 
    }
}
```